# There is another function to calculate $T_n$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

I was searching about Fibonacci numbers, and I found that Tribonacci numbers also exist given the following recurrence: $T_{n+3}= T_{n+2}+T_{n+1}+T{n}$  with $T_0=T_1=0,T_2=1$. Then I thought about what would be a function that would calculate the value $T_n$ and it would obviously be: $ F (n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) - F(n-3) $, please correct me if it is not So. But, is there another way (function) to calculate this value without having to use recurrences?

Comment: do you know the formula to compute Fibonacci without recurrence?

Comment: Also, do you know the general solution of the cubic (analogous to quadratic formula)?

Comment: solve $x^3=x^2+x+1$ then $T_n=\sum \alpha_i (r_i)^n$ where the $r_i$ are roots. (but these are not nice roots...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can solve the recurrence relation $F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)+F(n-3)$ by solving its characteristic polynomial $x^3 = x^2 + x + 1$.  This has a real solution $\alpha$ and two complex solutions $\beta, \gamma$, so the function will be given by $$F(n) = c_1 \alpha^n + c_2 \beta^n + c_3 \gamma^n$$ and we need to solve for $c_1, c_2, c_3$.  We do this by substituting in the initial conditions:

\begin{align*}
0 = F(1) &= c_1 + c_2 + c_3 \\
0 = F(2) &= c_1 \alpha + c_2 \beta + c_3 \gamma \\
1 = F(3) &= c_1 \alpha^2 + c_2 \beta^2 + c_3 \gamma^2,
\end{align*}

so we have to solve a system of $3$ equations and $3$ unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

You can use some matrix algebra

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
F_{n+2}\\
F_{n+1}\\
F_n
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 &0\\
0 & 1& 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} F_{n+1}\\ F_n\\ F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}
$$

Denote the matrix above by $A$ and then notice that if $\mathbf{V}_n:=[F_{n+2},F_{n+1},F_n]^\top$, then

$$ \mathbf{V}_n = A^n \mathbf{V}_1$$

Still, you have to do some work. Maybe see if you can find a spectral decomposition of $A$ (i.e.  convenient canonical form)  and which will allow you to compute things "faster".

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be the matrix $\pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1\cr 1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 1 & 0\cr}$.
Then the third column of $M^n$ is $\pmatrix{T_{n+1}\cr T_{n}\cr T_{n-1}}$.
You can compute $M^n$ very quickly using [repeated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Answer (score 0):

To do this numerically, it helps to remark that the cubic $x^3=x^2+x+1$ has three roots, only one of which has norm greater than $1$. Call that root $\alpha$.  We note that, numerically, it is about $$\alpha \sim 1.83928675521416$$ It follows that, for large $n$, we have $T_n\sim C\alpha^n$ for some constant $C$.  Numerically it looks like $C\sim .18280$.

Of course, this method is limited by the accuracy of our numerical estimates.  There is a closed form for $\alpha$ if you prefer, but it isn't pretty:

$$\alpha = \frac 13\times  \left(1 + (19 -  \sqrt {33})^{1/3} + (19 + 3 \sqrt {33
}))^{1/3}\right)$$